# Sender's and Receiver's progress bar out of sync

Tags: sockets, file-io, android-asynctask, progress-bar, android-notifications

I'm facing a strange problem while dealing with Android `ProgressBar`. I've written a socket based file transfer application. The file transfer works fine and the progress bar at server side is also in sync with transferred file size. However, at receiver's end, the progress bar reaches to 100% very soon (while the transfer of file from server is still in progress). Any idea what could be the reason for that? Here is the receiver's side implementation using `AsyncTask`:

```
private class ConnectToServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    int mNotificationId;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Build notification object

        mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder= new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Airwire")
        .setContentText("Copy in progress")
        .setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationId = 001;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final EditText ipText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipText);
        try {
            serverIP=InetAddress.getByName(ipText.getText().toString());
            socket = new Socket(serverIP, 4444);
            if (socket != null) {
                InputStream min=socket.getInputStream();
                int filecount=min.read(); //read file count from server
                for (int j = 0; j < filecount; j++){
                    try {
                        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                        int buffersize = socket.getReceiveBufferSize();
                        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(in);
                        String recFileName = clientData.readUTF(); // read file name
                        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                                downloadFolderPath +"/" + recFileName);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                        long filesize = clientData.readLong(); // read file size
                        double nosofpackets=Math.ceil(filesize/buffer.length);
                        long z = filesize;
                        int n = 0;

                        int k=1;

                        while ((z > 0)
                                && (n = clientData.read(buffer, 0,
                                        (int) Math.min(buffer.length, z))) != -1) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
                            int progressint=(int)(k*100/nosofpackets);
                            publishProgress(Math.min(progressint, 100));
                            Log.d("PROGRESSINT", progressint+"");
                            output.flush();
                            z -= n;
                            k++;
                        }
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        //update notification bar
        mBuilder.setContentText("Copy in progress: "+values[0]+"%");
        if (values[0]%2==0){
            mBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
            mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }       
}
```

I'm building a notification object (with progress bar) in `preExecute()`. To avoid frequent notification updates, I'm notifying only for progress in multiple of 2. Please refer to the method I've used to calculate `progressint` in `doInBackground()`. Is it the correct way to calculate file transfer progress? Any help would be highly appreciated!